# Peewee install error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat - Microsoft server 2012 R2

Tags: python, batch-file, peewee

I need help to install peewee on an server version Microsoft server 2012 R2. In this server I need to use IIS.

I create an API whose use peewee to process with a distant database.
In the server I installed python 3.4.2 and wgfastgci via microsolft plateform installer :

When Python is installed, I used pip list I just had setuptools and pip installed.
To install peewee I did :
pip install peewee
but I had this error :

```
Peewee install error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I tried to do these steps but did not work :

- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/peewee-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsallbat
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

when I upgraded setuptools with pip the error changed like that :

```
error : Microsoft Visual c++ 10.0 i srequired. get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1" : www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

So I tried to do this :

But all the links were not compatibles with windows server 2012 R2 ... I would not like install SDK in a server. So I searched others versions in microsoft web site and I got these but it was not work.

I need help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when trying to compile a C extension:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: Yes, I got this response... I was trying but it is for windows 7 version. I "need" to use windows version for server.